# Downcasting template typename object in C++

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have the following function in a C++ application that is called many different times:

```
template<typename The_ValueType>
void
handleObject(The_ValueType const &the_value)  //unchangable function signature
{ 
    /*
        //Pseudo Java code (not sure how to implement in C++)
        if (the_value instanceof Person){
            Person person = (Person) the_value      
            //do something with person
        }
        if (the_value instanceof Integer){
           int theInt = (Integer) the_value
           //do something with int
        }
    */
}
```

I need to print out some debugging information from the "the_value" object.  Unfortunately, I'm from a Java/JavaScript background, and I'm horribly inefficient and unknowledable with C++.  When I try to downcast in C++, I keep getting the error "invalid target type for dynamic_cast".  How can implement the "Pseudo Java code" listed?  Basically, I just need to know how to do the downcast,  be the object a primitive or an object.  I'm ripping my hair out trying to understand pointers and casting, and any guidance would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Code such as this, which may be fairly common in Java, is an anti-pattern in C++. If your design requires hard-coding runtime variable dispatch, chances are your design needs improving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing about downcasting here. You should use [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

```
template<typename The_ValueType>
void
handleObject(const The_ValueType &the_value)
{ 
    // default implementation: do nothing or something else
}

template<>
void
handleObject<Person>(const Person &the_value)
{ 
    //do something with the_value as Person
}

template<>
void
handleObject<int>(const int &the_value)
{ 
    //do something with the_value as int
}
```

Or even better if all types are known, you can use overloading:

```
void handleObject(const Person &the_value)
{ 
    //do something with the_value as Person
}

void handleObject(const int &the_value)
{ 
    //do something with the_value as int
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was extremely helpful, and saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Overloading would be even better.